# for loop to identify outlier value and row corresponding to it data frame in R

Tags: r, outliers

I have a data frame having 85 variables out of which around 60 are numeric. I would like determine the outlier value (I am using the Outliers package) for the numeric columns at one shot maybe using a 'for loop' and also the rows corresponding to the outlier value in the data frame.

**Note:  the rows corresponding to the outlier value may be > 1 for each outlier value.**

The code written for now is below. I have created a few appropriate null vectors before the loop and inserted the values into these vectors. After the execution of the loop I have populated the vectors into a new data frame.

**My Problem: I am not able to identify the rows in data frame which has that particular outlier value. This may be because each outlier value may be present in more than one row. The OutlierRow2 has the values  but I am not able to convert it to data.frame. I request some one to please help me.**

```
## initialize null vectors 
numericVariables <- NULL
OutlierValue <- NULL
OutlierRow2 <- NULL

# for loop to identify the outlier of numeric columns of a data.frame and save it in appropriate vectors
for(col in names(Table1))
{
  if(class(Table1[,col])=='numeric')
  {
    numericVariables = c(numericVariables,col)
    OutlierValue = c(OutlierValue,outlier(Table1[,col]))
    outlierRow2 = which(Table1[,col] == OutlierValue)
  }
}

# create the Outlier Table data frame with the vector values obtained above 
OutlierTable <- data.frame(numericVariables,OutlierValue,OutlierRow2)
```

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example here. A mock data frame  for `Table1`.

Comment: @amarchin: I am not able to understand what you are trying to convey. Could you please explain ?

Comment: We can't run your sample code on our machines so we can help you, because we don't have the `Table1` variable.  In Interactive R, go `dput(Table1)` and copy-paste the output into your question (you can edit your question by clicking the `edit` link above the comments)